# ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined (Running test with Mocha)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mocha.js, phaser-framework

I try to test my javascript application with Phaser 3, Mocha and NodeJS.
And if i run the test command "npm test" I get the following error:

How can i fix this?

This is the error message which i get everytime:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import phaser from 'phaser';
                                                                     ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\gamejam-challenge-nov18\test\appTest.js:2:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\gamejam-challenge-nov18\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:250:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\gamejam-challenge-nov18\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:247:14)
    at Mocha.run (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\gamejam-challenge-nov18\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:576:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\gamejam-challenge-nov18\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:637:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

This is the test I wrote (using Mocha):

```
   // appTest.js
    var assert = require('chai').assert;
const isRowFreeFunc = require('../app').isRowFree;

describe('function', function(){
    it('should be free', function(){
        gameField = [
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
        ];

        var result = isRowFreeFunc(6);
        assert.equal(result, true);
    })
});
```

This is my nodejs configuration:

```
 // package.json
    {
      "name": "testing101",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "parcel index.html",
        "test": "mocha"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "jest": "^22.4.4",
        "parcel-bundler": "^1.7.0",
        "phaser": "^3.15.1"
      },
      "jest": {
        "verbose": true,
        "testURL": "http://localhost:1234/"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "phaser": "^3.1.0",
        "mocha": "^5.2.0"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/kippenvogel/gamejam-challenge-nov18.git"
      },
      "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/kippenvogel/gamejam-challenge-nov18/issues"
      },
      "homepage": "https://github.com/kippenvogel/gamejam-challenge-nov18#readme"
    }
```

This is a part of my Application (reduced):

```
// app.js
import phaser from 'phaser';

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 900,
        height: 800,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };
// IS ROW FREE OR FULL
    /***
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     *  true = free
     *  false = full
     */
    module.exports = {
        isRowFree: function(row) {

            // ROW IS FULL
            if (gameField[0][row] == 1 ||
                gameField[0][row] == 2){
                    console.log(gameField);
                    console.log("ROW (" + row + ") is full!");
                    return false;
            }
            // ROW IS FREE
            else {
                var hh = getHeigthOfColumn(row);
                console.log ("Free Stones: " + hh);
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

function getHeigthOfColumn(column){
        var stones = 5;
        for (stones; stones >= 0; stones = stones-1){
            // FREE FOR MIN. 1 STONE
            if (gameField[stones][column] == 0){
                break;
            }
            if (gameField[stones][column] == 1 || gameField[stones][column] == 2 ){
            }
        }

        console.log( "Free Stones in Column(" +  column+"): " + stones);

        return stones;

}
```

Comment: You either need to compile your code with babel or use `require` instead of import.

Comment: I did add "var express = require('phaser');" to app.js. Now I get this error: C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub\gamejam-challenge-nov18\node_modules\phaser\src\polyfills\AudioContextMonkeyPatch.js:60
  if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitAudioContext') &&
  ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: nodejs does not provide DOM by default. You need to use something like [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to run your code against a specific DOM tree.

Comment: How can i do this? I installed JSDOM and added 'const jsdom = require('jsdom')
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;' in the test.js